# how do I get a ROUTER -> DEALER to echo?

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I'm trying to build the back half of a [Paranoid Pirate Pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Robust-Reliable-Queuing-Paranoid-Pirate-Pattern), a ROUTER that sends work out to a set of DEALER nodes (it's possible that I'm misundertanding the diagram). For now I just want the DEALERs to echo the work back or just send back a message that says "done". The problem is that the worker node (DEALER) is never receiving any messages.

```
var buildSocket, connectionTemplate, delay, frontPort, log, q, qPort, worker, workerPort, zmq;

zmq = require("zmq");    
frontPort = 5000;    
qPort = 5100;    
workerPort = 5200;    
connectionTemplate = "tcp://127.0.0.1:";    
log = console.log;    
debugger;    
delay = process.argv[2] || 1000;

buildSocket = function(desc, socketType, port) {
  var socket;
  log("creating " + socketType + " socket");
  socket = zmq.socket(socketType);
  socket.identity = "" + desc + "-" + socketType + "-" + process.pid + "-" + port;
  return socket;
};

q = buildSocket('q_output', 'router', qPort);

worker = buildSocket('worker', 'dealer', workerPort);

worker.bind("" + connectionTemplate + workerPort);

q.connect("" + connectionTemplate + workerPort);

q.on('message', function() {
  var args;
  args = Array.apply(null, arguments);
  log('queue received ' + JSON.stringify(arguments));
  return worker.send('work done');
});

worker.on('message', function() {
  var args;
  log('back received ' + JSON.stringify(arguments));
  args = Array.apply(null, arguments);
  return q.send(args);
});

setInterval((function() {
  var value;
  value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  console.log(q.identity + ": sending " + value);
  q.send(value);
}), delay);
```

The queue and worker `on 'message'` events never fire. The way I understand this is you set up the ROUTER node, bind it to a port (for return messages), set up the DEALER nodes and bind them to a port then connect the ROUTER to the DEALER port and start sending messages. In practice, messages are sent but never received:

```
creating router socket
creating dealer socket
q_output-router-60326-5100: sending 30
q_output-router-60326-5100: sending 25
q_output-router-60326-5100: sending 65
q_output-router-60326-5100: sending 68
q_output-router-60326-5100: sending 50
q_output-router-60326-5100: sending 88
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got things a little backwards, here.  Think of a `DEALER` socket as a modified `REQ` socket... it should be initiating your messages to your router.  A `ROUTER` socket is more like a modified `REP` socket... it should be responding to the initial request sent by your dealer.

You don't *strictly* need to follow that pattern with `ROUTER/DEALER` pairings... but it definitely makes things *much* easier, so you should stick with it while you're learning.

The second thing that sticks out to me from your code is that you message handlers, you've got the wrong socket sending messages.

Take for instance this code (directly copied without modification):

```
q.on('message', function() {
  var args;
  args = Array.apply(null, arguments);
  log('queue received ' + JSON.stringify(arguments));
  return worker.send('work done');
});
```

... that says (in psuedocode):

```
when `q` receives a message from `worker`
  print out the message we received
  now have `worker` send *another* message that says "work done"
```

What you want is something more like the following (simplified):

```
var zmq = require("zmq");
var q = zmq.socket('router');
var worker = zmq.socket('dealer');

// I've switched it so the router is binding and the worker is connecting
// this is somewhat arbitrary, but generally I'd consider workers to be less
// reliable, more transient, and also more numerous. I'd think of the queue
// as the "server"

// I've used bindSync, which is synchronous, but that's typically OK in the
// startup phase of a script, and it simplifies things.  If you're spinning
// up new sockets in the middle of your script, using the async bind()
// is more appropriate
q.bindSync('tcp://127.0.0.1:5200');

worker.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5200');

q.on('message', function() {
  var args;
  args = Array.apply(null, arguments);
  log('queue received ' + JSON.stringify(arguments));

  // if we've received a message at our queue, we know the worker is ready for
  // more work, so we ready some new data, regardless of whether we
  // received work back
  var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

  // note that the socket that received the message is responding back
  if (args[1].toString() == 'ready') console.log('worker now online');
  else console.log('work received: '+args[1].toString());

  // we need to specify the "ID" of our worker as the first frame of
  // the message
  q.send([args[0], value]);

  // we don't need to return anything, the return value of a
  // callback is ignored
});

worker.on('message', function() {
  var args;
  log('back received ' + JSON.stringify(arguments));
  args = Array.apply(null, arguments);

  // we're just echoing back the "work" we received from the queue
  // for additional "workiness", we wait somewhere between 10-1000
  // milliseconds to respond
  setTimeout(function() {
    worker.send(args[0].toString());
  }, parseInt(args[0].toString())*10);
});

setTimeout((function() {
  var value;
  console.log('WORKER STARTING UP');

  // the worker starts the communication, indicating it's ready
  // rather than the queue just blindly sending work
  worker.send('ready'); // sending the first message, which we catch above
}), 500); // In my experience, half a second is more than enough, YMMV
```

... as you can see, the pattern is:

1. Worker indicates readiness
2. Queue sends available work
3. Worker completes work and sends back
4. Queue receives completed work and sends back more work
5. GOTO 3

Comment: damn, did you write all that for this post (as in, didn't have any of it 'just around')?

Comment: lol, yeah, I wrote it for this, but most of the code was only minimally modified from what you already had, and the description was fairly straight forward :)

Comment: are you sure those timers should be `setInterval`? I'm thinking a `setTimeout` would be better... as it is every hit to the worker's message event is starting up a timer that's sending a message back. the message count grows exponentially

Comment: hey @Jason can you look at this gist? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5c798962d39399cf0fb5 -- it looks to me like it should be sending out many messages but no matter what I do with the timings it will only send out one work packet at a time.

Comment: It's going to be tough to deal with that in the comments here, why don't you ask a new question with your new code?